# Работа с буфером экрана консоли с++

Tags: c++, консоль

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как работать с буфером экрана консоли. Я знаю, что все водимые данные в консоль хранятся в буфере в виде двумерного массива, но как обратиться к нему, как получить из него данные, я не знаю. Помогите

Comment: "что все водимые данные в консоль хранятся в буфере в виде двумерного массива". Откуда вы это знаете, если это не так? Реализации всегда разные, хоть и интерфейс одинаков.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/console/console-screen-buffers **Буфер экрана — это двумерный массив символов и данных о цвете для вывода в окне консоли. Консоль может иметь несколько буферов экрана. Буфер активного экрана отображается на экране.**

Comment: каждая фирма предоставляет свою реализацию и может не в полной мере открыть/вскрыть детали. Пользователю  это не должно волновать, но чтобы дать представление,  могут в документации сказать: "представьте, что это так(это не важно)". Ведь спокойно можно  вместо буфера использовать структуру данных со стеком или матричным классом, который вовсе не хранит двумерный массив.

Comment: [Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window) из доки по вашей ссылке, как к этому подступться. / (А вы хорошо подумали, зачем вам сейчас эта виндузятина нужна?)

Answer (score 0):

Как вы хотите работать, знаете только вы. Обращаться к буферу напрямую можно(а иногда нужно, если вы пишете код низкого уровня(например свой поток). Буфер потока в конкретно в `С++` представлен классом  `basic_streambuf<char, char_traits<char>>` и имеетcя определение специализации `std::streambuf` (для char), и он имеет много методов, и что для чего, можно почитать в документации. Но вот маленький пример:

```
char a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
//получим указатель на буфер потока ввода
std::streambuf* buf = cin.rdbuf();   
//вернем символ в буфер
buf->sungetc();
//посмотрим что за символ
char c = buf->sgetc();      

cout << a << b << c;
//теперь вводим содержимое буфера в буфер
//потока вывода(там у нас еще остался
//последный символ  буфера, плюс
//что введем до символа EOF
buf = cout.rdbuf();
cin >> buf;  
//введем "ab" выведим "abbb" и все что введем дальше
```

Внутреннее представление буфера зависит от реализации, а также есть языковая зависимость.